# Can you set a specific session variable to live for only 5 minutes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

Is there a way regarding `ASP.NET Webforms` to set the time to live for a session variable to be 5 minutes?

For instance if I have the variable:

```
Session["Name"] = "Bob";
```

After 5 minutes I'd like it to be destroyed, or at least be able to nullify it.

Example:

```
Session["Name"] = null;
//But in the background and not code-controlled as it has to be live over multiple pages.
```

I know that these Session variables expire upon timeout which is controlled within IIS, but I'm trying to expire them before the timeout occurs at intervals of 5 minutes, is this possible?

Comment: no its not possible, but you can add a time stamp and check if the 5 minutes are pass

Comment: `sessionState`? or perhaps `setTimeout` in JS that checks the time

Comment: @Aristos would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @user5173426 I imagine that could be a problem if you use JS to do this if you run it client side if it's critical to destroy the Session variable every 5 minutes and the client-side JS is disabled which would mean doing it between posts server-side, is there a way around doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create two session values (or a single object which contains the two values, which I'd likely prefer but for simplicity let's just use two values to illustrate), one with the value and one with its expiry time.

```
Session["Name"] = "Bob";
Session["NameExpiry"] = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
```

Then wherever you use that value, check its expiry:

```
if (Session["NameExpiry"] != null && DateTime.Parse(Session["NameExpiry"]) < DateTime.UtcNow)
{
    Session["Name"] = null;
    Session["NameExpiry"] = null;
}
```

You could throw in a variety of error checking, other logic on the values, etc.  But the principal is the same.  Essentially, don't think of it as trying to set some kind of background timer to actively expire the session data, think of storing the expiry time as part of the session data and silently expiring it the next time you use it after that time stamp.

Comment: I think I had the wrong way of thinking approaching this and this is a good solution and I can adapt it to meet my specific needs, so thank you. You were right about checking upon use, and not in the background.

Answer (score -1):

Since sessions are stored on the server side. create an action that can be called after 5 minutes from the client side.

```
public class ControllerName
{
   public ActionResult ClearSession()
   {
      Session = null;
   }
}
```

Then on the client-side:

```
<script>

    setTimeout(function(){  $.ajax('/ControllerName/ClearSession'); }, 300000);

</script>
```

After OP mentioned:

*The issue I have with this is that it's client-side controlled. I need it to work in the case of users that are preventing JS from running on pages*

```
Session["Name"] = "Bob";

//task that will run after the specified interval
Task.Delay(300000).ContinueWith((task) => {
    Session.Remove(Name);
});
```

Comment: The issue I have with this is that it's client-side controlled. I need it to work in the case of users that are preventing JS from running on pages.

Comment: @CaptainWibble Okay, I did not see that hiccup in the original question, editing and adding that scenario in the answer now.

Comment: Will that task really run *five minutes* after the original request?  Or would that whole thread be long gone by then?

Comment: That task will be killed after the page is loaded for the user.

Comment: After 5 minutes I'd like it to be destroyed, or at least be able to nullify it. Wasn't this the case?

Comment: The thread will be killed if it's asynchronous, if it isn't the user will be locked into a page load for that to be waited on